# how to search on the folded range in gvim?

Tags: vim

Here is the material to test the search function:

1. move cursor in the line 5
2. `zfG`  to fold line 5 until the end of the file. (please see the
   attachment1)

When I input  `?case`, I can get the attachment2

Now, let me add a line which contains only one word `case` in the first line, and fold line 6 until the end of the file too. When I input  `?case`, I can  only  get the  line 1, can not search line7?

How can I search on the folded lines?

The following is the raw material to test:

```
Note the use of ( ) with the pipe symbol to specify the 'or' condition    
/[0-9]*/MATches if there are zero or more numbers in the line    
/^[^#]/ Matches if the first character is not a # in the line    
Notes:    
1. Regular expressions are case sensitive    
2. Regular expressions are to be used where pattern is specifiedYou can jump back to beginning of file by typing any one of the following command
```

[image]
[image: attachment2]
[image: attachment3]

Comment: It works for me.  1. After landing on "case" in Line 1, do you try `n` to search again?  2. `:set wrapscan? foldopen?`

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Does it also occur with plain Vim (`vim -N -u NONE`)? Do you have any mapping on `n`?